# Size of imported 3D-Mesh is not realistic

Tags: mesh, import, obj

I imported a 3D-mesh of a coral fragment as an OBJ-file. The coral fragment is approximately 1cm x 2 cm. After importing it to Blender, I measured it and the size was way larger. The ruler function gave me 3m x 4m. I need to calculate the surface area and without the right size of the 3D model I cannot get the right surface area.

Comment: Hi :). *.obj files are often imported in a 10 000% scale. No idea why. Simply set scale of the model to 0.01 and you should be fine. And don't forget to apply the scale after :)

Comment: As @JachymMichal says, *.obj files and others created in different software not always use the same scale in Blender. I'm no expert in this, but as far as I know this comes from the way the data is stored and interpreted. For example, if the OBJ uses milimeter as base and stores an X value of 1000 for a vertex, than this should be 1 meter. But if Blender uses meter as base and just takes the 1000 as is because it expects 1 meter to be stored as 1.000, than suddenly the thing gets huge with an X value of 1000 meters. So if you know real world dimensions, you should scale the object accordingly.